# Android: fling detection on ListView with complex rows

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener

Dear Android hackers, I am attaching a gestureListener recognizing flings to a ListView. The rows of the ListView consist of a LinearView and some TextViews. Unfortunately, the fling is not detected, when it starts on one of the TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#333333"

        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, when I start the fling on the horizontal LinearLayout, everything works fine, but when I start it on the TextView at the bottom, nothing happens. It containts editable text, if that could be the problem... As is said, the Listener is attached to the ListView itself.

I'd be glad if somebody could help!

Jan Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your editable TextView is returning `true` from `onTouch()`, preventing the event from being processed by the `LinearLayout` higher up the view hierarchy.

There is nothing stopping you attaching a custom `OnTouchListener` to your `TextView` to override this and pass the event to your existing `GestureDetector`.

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent ev) {             
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }           
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. I will try this in a couple of days.